# Division error calculating coins needed for correct change

Tags: c#

I am experiencing some issues when attempting to find out the least amount of coins needed in order to dispense the correct change. Please refer the the source below:

```
int[] change_given = new int[coins.Length];
int coin;
for (int i = 0; i < coins.Length; i++)
{
    coin = Math.Min(quantities[i], (int)(change / coins[i]));
    change -= coin * coins[i];
    change_given[i] = coin;
}
return change_given;
```

For some strange reason, there appears to be an issue when attempting the current change value comes down to the last 5 cents. Please refer to the example output below:
[image]

The Quantity represents the amount of times the the current coin is divisible by the change.
Coin values are located on the far left hand side of the output. As you can see the last 0.05 cents quantity which is set to 0, and incorrect. The quantity for this should be set to 1, considering that the current change value is set to 0.05. The data type for coins[i] is double and change is also set to a typeof double. Please advise what the issue is here, and a possible work around.

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger and find out in seconds. It could simply be an issue with representing floating point values. Since this has to do with money, you should *definitely* be using `decimal` instead of `float`.

Comment: Or post the entire code not just fractions of it...

Comment: Solved using 'decimal' as pointed out by @Jon.

Comment: Why work in fractions at all, work in whole cents and your problems go away.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't intended to be an answer to the OP's question. I just thought I'd try to make a functional LINQ-based solution to finding the change similar to the results that this question is looking for. Here it is:

```
Func<int, IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<int>> getChange = null;
getChange = (a, cs) =>
    cs.Any()
        ? (a >= cs.First()
            ? cs.Take(1).Concat(getChange(a - cs.First(), cs))
            : getChange(a, cs.Skip(1)))
        : Enumerable.Empty<int>();
```

Now I can use this to find the change:

```
var coins = new [] { 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, };
var change = getChange(425, coins);
```

That gives me this result:

[image: results]

Like I said, and apart from the fact that this eliminates the use of division, this doesn't answer this question. I just thought I'd post it for the "pure" joy of it. (Pardon the pun.)

---

F# implementation as requested in comments:

```
let rec GetChange a cs =
    match cs with
    | []    -> []
    | x::xs -> if a >= x
               then x::(GetChange (a - x) cs)
               else GetChange a xs

GetChange 425 [200; 100; 50; 20; 10; 5]
```

Comment: @abatishchev - I had to roll back your edit. Since the function is recursive you must do the double assignment.

Comment: Oh, cool, thanks for clarification. Can you write the same in F# btw? :)

Comment: @abatishchev - I'm keen to learn f#, but I've only really dabbled. I'm not up to translating this code yet I think. Perhaps I should try. Why do you want it in f#?

Comment: If C# code is written in functional style it's a good candidate to be written in F# instead, I think. Especially it should be interesting for those who learn F#. Such as me or you :)

Comment: @abatishchev - I've included an F# implementation. It does seem to be a pretty easy conversion.